# Python regex to match one or more line breaks?

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a text file into paragraphs, separated by 1 or more empty lines.
For example:

```
# file.txt
"Paragraph1
Some text

Paragraph2
More text

Paragraph3
some more text"
```

I tried using regex, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. In the example I'm trying to print the second paragraph only, but I get a `list index out of range` error. But when I print `p[0]` it prints the whole text file. What am I doing wrong? Should I use a different regex expression? Or other methods to split the file into paragraphs?

```py
with open(file) as f:
    text = f.read()

p = text.split("[\r\n]+")
print(p[1])
```

Comment: The `+` and `[]` that you have are regex metacharacters. Python's regular `str.split()` does not accept regex arguments.

Comment: Ahh I see, then it seems like "\n\n" should work

Comment: *it seems like "\n\n" should work * Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.split()`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[\r\n][\r\n]+', text)
['Paragraph1\nSome text', 'Pragraph2\nMore text', 'Paragraph3\nsome more text']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because you didn't split your text (and so, don't have a second element), instead you could use this separator:

```
p = text.split("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a single space in the texts using the below.

import re

fin = open("data.txt", "rt")
fout = open("out.txt", "wt")

for line in fin:
fout.write(re.sub('\s+',' ',line))

fin.close()
fout.close()